# Subscribe to newsletter Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, newsletter, unsubscribe

After some research i have found that there is no easy simple plug and play solution to simply subscribe to a newsletter in CIVI from a Wordpress site. All the solution are too much forms plugins, processor etc.. Actually i'm using a "profile" solution but it's not as clean as i liked.

I need someone to help develop a simple but effective Newsletter Signup Wordpress plugin, in short:

Signup

- Display on a page a newsletter signup form (shortcode ok)
- On Ajax submit Check if contact already exist or create it
- Add Contact to group with status "onHold"
- Send an email confirmation to the email
- On validation Change status to "current"
- Send an email confirmation to the email

Unsubscribe

- Display on a page a newsletter unsubscribe form (shortcode ok)
- On Ajax submit Check if contact already exist
- Send an email confirmation to the email
- On validation confirmation Change status to "removed"

If someone is interested, please answer here. I have already developed part of the plugin (form display and group api), but there are some civi part (send email with tokens for example) which i need help.

ps: the plugin code will be public.

ps2: this is a paid development

Comment: I think you will need to define the requirement in case of multiple group subscriptions. Probably we can help to build one for you or civicrm experts https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Comment: We have built an extension that deals with similar requirements: https://docs.civicrm.org/newsletter/en/latest/ However to render the public form in a WordpressCMS you would need to build a Wordpress Endpoint that exchanges data with the CiviCRM Extension/API (currently there is only one for Drupal). Maybe worth checking ^^

Comment: @Fabian nice !  i will have a look. Adding a wordpress endpoint can be the solution i'm looking